# return (a) vs. return a

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I have seen both in the C and C++ code I have been looking at.

What is the difference?

Comment: The only difference is that you should run screaming from any code base that is rife with the former.

Comment: Please refrain from adding an hyphen to your question titles. It does not change its sort order or anything. All it does it break the search feature.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No difference at all.

The official syntax is `return something;` or `return;` and of course it is a keyword, not a function.

For this reason you should not read it as `return( a );` but as `return (a);`
I think the difference is subtle but clear, parentheses will not apply to return but to a.

`((((a))))` is the same as `(a)` that is the same as `a`.

You can also write something like...

```
int x = (((100)));
```

You can also write something like...

```
printf("%d\n", (z));
```

As someone said in the comments, there is now, with C++11 (2011 version of the C++ language) the new operator `decltype`. This operator introduces a new example where `(a)` is different from `a`, this is quite esoteric and a little out of topic but I add this example just for the purpose of completeness.

```
    int x = 10;
    decltype(x) y = x;   // this means int y = x;
    decltype((x)) z = x; // this means int& z = x;
    y = 20;
    z = 30;
    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
    // this will print out "30 20 30"
```

Students will not be interested in this, as I said, too esoteric, and it will work only with compilers that supports at least part of the C++11 standard (like GCC 4.5+ and Visual Studio 2010).

This goes in contrast also with the use of `typeid` keyword:

```
int a;
std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl; // will print "int"
std::cout << typeid((a)).name() << std::endl; // will print "int" !!!!
```

Comment: Isn't `(a)` an expression that returns a reference to `a`?  I seem to remember hearing that somewhere.  If that is true, then they are not truly the same, but "same enough" to not matter here.  Although `(100)` obviously shouldn't be a reference... Hmmm...

Comment: Therefore, don't add the parens to return statements in your own code.

Comment: Yes I absolutely agree AShelly, but there is nothing wrong in doing that, except confusing students.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: There are indeed context's where `()` matters. For example, given `int i;`, `decltype(i)` is `int` while `decltype((i))` is `int&`. The `(i)` makes it an expression, and it returns the type of the expression, while `i` is just an identifier. Since `return`  is just going to use the value, this makes no difference.

Comment: Well... is the type of the expression `(i)` different in C++11 or is it just most visibly demonstrated by use of `decltype`?

Comment: @MichaelPrice: You should type @*username* so they're notified of your response. AFAIK, it's the same in C++03, but there's no context in which is makes a difference because the direct acquisition of type names was only introduced with `decltype`.

Comment: "_Students will not be interested in this_" They will. (Or at least should.) It means: do not learn this language. The designers went crazy. It can only get worse.

Comment: @MichaelPrice There was never a difference between the context-independent expression `x` and `(x)`, in C or in C++. According to that, the designers of `decltype` went crazy, and there was no one to stop them.

Comment: @curiousguy: Well I agree that some new thing of the new standard sounds a bit, how to say, "weird", but at least, you are free to not use decltype if you don't want to.

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti Clearly the committee wanted to do two different things. I can guess that `decltype(expr)` is the type `T` such that a function `f ()` returning `T` makes the expression `f()` type-equivalent with `expr`. OTOH, `decltype(id)` is expected to have the declared type of `id`.

Comment: Since C, we understand that the fact that `f(x);` can be a declaration or a function call has annoying consequences. With C++, there is even more fun: it can also be a cast. `f(g)(x);` can be two function calls or a declaration, or a cast followed by a function call? `Type x(f(g));` can be a declaration of a variable or a function. But someone wanted to have even more fun.

Comment: @GMan : Is it possible that using `return (movable);` rather than `return movable;` inhibits implicit `std::move` on the return value?

Comment: @ildjarn: That's (surprisingly) only an allowed optimization, and not required, so technically it's up to your specific compiler. I can't see it making a difference. That said, I know in MSVC2010, given `T foo(T x)`, if you make that `{ return x; }` it'll elison the copy/move, but if you do `{ return std::move(x); }` it'll move-construct and never elison. A bit silly if you ask me.

Comment: @curiousguy: There always was, since K&R 1. If `x` is a function-style macro, `x` refers to the macro but `(x)` does not.

Answer (score 12):

Writing `return x` indicates a programmer who understands what `return` means. Whereas `return(x)` indicates a programmer who incorrectly believes that `return` is a kind of function.

Comment: Every time I see return(x) I wish I were a more violent person.

Answer (score 3):

`return` is not a function.

It is more a point of style.  I personally do not use parentheses in a return statement unless it is showing order of operations.

examples

```
return a;
return (a || b);
return (a && (b || c));
return (a ? b : c);
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother with the outer parentheses in any of those: `return a ? b : c;`