# Java - Difference between "return object" and "return (object)"

Tags: java

Is there any special difference between (maybe compiler level?)

```
public byte[] getSalt() {
    return salt;
}
```

and

```
public byte[] getSalt() {
    return (salt);
}
```

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: For the similar C/C++ question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943052/return-a-vs-return-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,  unless you are typecasting..

```
public byte[] getSalt() {
    return (byte[])salt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing `return x` indicates a programmer who understands what `return` means. Whereas `return(x)` indicates a programmer who incorrectly believes that `return` is a kind of function.