# How can we load a URL in webView that it wants to storing client-side data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

**It is my first test with `webViwe`.**

When i run a base `URL ="https://baseUrl.com"` in web browser it load and then URL will change to
`"https://baseUrl.com/login"` like this :

**Step one :**

[image]

**Step two:**

[image]

But when i load `"https://baseUrl.com"` or `"https://baseUrl.com/login"` in mobile `webView` i just faced with **step one** and it never goes to **step two**.

**This is my codes :**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
  with(webView.settings) {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        loadWithOverviewMode = true
        useWideViewPort = true
    }
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    
        webView.loadUrl("https://baseUrl/login")
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i found in websites that take advantage [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) storage we should add this in setting `webView` :

```
 webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello 
 I think this problem is from your web side 
As far as I know your site will be moved to the next page by calling the next site 
 
Did you call your next site ...

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer , what did you mean about next site? we have a base URL and just address change after the base URl like : `https://baseURL/login` or `https://baseURL/authentication`  and it works on web browser after step one we going to step two but in mobile `webView` it trapped on step one.