# Copy assignment operator returning *this vs (*this)

Tags: c++, reference, this

Is there a difference between

```cpp
class MyString {
...
    MyString &operator=(MyString other) {
        swap(s, other.s);
        return (*this);
    }
};
```

and

```cpp
class MyString {
...
    MyString &operator=(MyString other) {
        swap(s, other.s);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I read in some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560449/parentheses-around-return-values-why) that adding parenthesis indicates that you are returning by reference rather than value. But in case the return type is defined, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: In your case, the additional parenthesis don't make any difference. Use whichever coding style you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you have cited discusses a different situation. In this case

```
*this == (*this)
```

It depends on your preference since both of them will do exactly the same thing. Personally, I'd prefer `*this` to avoid unnecessary parenthesis

[Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) can sometimes change the way you want to de-reference something. Imagine this situation

```cpp
*my_vector[0]
```

What do you think will happen here? Is it doing

```cpp
(*my_vector)[0]
```

Or

```
*(my_vector[0])
```

The correct answer is the second one. Sometimes you might want to change this behavior, and that's when `()` come.